# Pyside6 - How to call parent method in child method class

Tags: python, qt, pyside6

I want to call a father method inside a child class method but I'm having some trouble and missing some points.
I'm able to call parent's method just inside def__init__(self)
How to solve?

I tried:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    ws = websocket.WebSocket()
    threadpool = QThreadPool()
    pippo = "pippo"
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        tabs = QTabWidget()
        tabs.setTabPosition(QTabWidget.North)
        tabs.setMovable(False)
        tabs.setDocumentMode(True)
        self.voices = Widget("Voices", self)
        tabs.addTab(self.voices, "Voices")
        self.setCentralWidget(tabs)
    def do_something(self):
        print ('doing something!')

class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, name, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Widget()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.name=name
        self.lan = str(config_ini("language"))
        self.username = str(config_ini("user"))
        print(self.parent().pippo) #HERE MY CODE WORKS
        self.parent().do_something()  #HERE MY CODE WORKS
      
        self.ui.InitializeButton.clicked.connect(self.clickedInitialize)
        
#Pressione tasto Initialize
    def clickedInitialize(self):
        self.parent().do_something()  #HERE MY CODE ___DON'T___ WORKS
```

and I receive this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\IENOGIUS\Documents\Cefla\VoiceCommands\VoiceChecker\voicechecker.py", line 294, in clickedInitialize
    self.parent().do_something()
AttributeError: 'PySide6.QtWidgets.QStackedWidget' object has no attribute 'do_something'
```

Comment: Assuming that the `QMainWindow` is the top level window you could also use the `self.window()` method to access the main window.  But as it has been stated this is also not the recommended approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [`addTab()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtabwidget.html#addTab) documentation explains:

> Ownership of page is passed on to the QTabWidget.

This would be true anyway whenever you add a widget to another, making it a *child* of that new *parent*.
In this case, it happens when `tabs.addTab(self.voices, "Voices")`, which *reparents* the widget to the tab widget (actually, its internal QStackedWidget): the window becomes the *ancestor* of the `Widget` instance, the actual parent is the stacked widget.

The structure will be the following:

- MainWindow

  - QTabWidget

    - QStackedWidget (internally used by QTabWidget to display pages)

      - Widget

If you want to keep a reference to the main window, just use an instance attribute in the `__init__` (eg. `self.mainWindow = parent`).

Note, though, that child objects should **never** directly call methods of their ancestors (see ["separation of concerns"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)), and signals also exist for this very reason.

What you should actually do is to connect the signal from the window:

```py
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        self.voices = Widget("Voices", self)
        self.voices.ui.InitializeButton.clicked.connect(self.do_something)
```

And obviously remove that connection from `Widget`.

Alternatively, a better approach should use a custom signal instead:

```py
class Widget(QWidget):
    do_something_signal = Signal()
    # ...

    def clickedInitialize(self):
        # do whatever you need, then:
        self.do_something_signal.emit()


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        self.voices.do_something_signal.connect(self.do_something)
```

I suggest you to read more about the Qt [object trees and ownerships](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/objecttrees.html) and also possible proper usage of signals in complex object structures in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70692825).

<sup>Note: please avoid using code comments that are not necessary for the understanding of the code, especially if in languages that are not English. And, really, don't use "pippo".</sup>