# How to correctly create parent/child relationship between two windows in pyqt6

Tags: python-3.x, parent-child, pyqt6

I am a beginner trying to learn python and pyqt6

I have a MainWindow, where I can click on File-->New connection to open a second window

If I understand correctly, the second window should be a child of the MainWindow

When I click on "New connection", the app seems to freeze and the second window doesn't open. However, if I don't pass self as an argument when I create the second window, then it works.

I think I'm not creating the relationship correctly between MainWindow and the second window

thank you for your help

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(QMainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.resize(400, 200)
        self.centralWidget = QLabel("central widget!")
        self.centralWidget.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignVCenter)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.createActions()
        self.createMenu()
        self.connectActions()
        

    def createMenu(self):
        menuBar = self.menuBar()
        self.setMenuBar(menuBar)
        fileMenu = QMenu("File", self)
        menuBar.addMenu(fileMenu)
        fileMenu.addAction(self.newConnect)
        fileMenu.addSeparator()
        fileMenu.addAction(self.exit)

    def createActions(self):
        self.newConnect = QAction("New Connection", self)
        self.exit = QAction("Exit", self)
        self.newConnect.setShortcut("Ctrl+N")
    
    def connectActions(self):
        self.exit.triggered.connect(self.exitAction)
        self.newConnect.triggered.connect(self.newConnectAction)
        

    def exitAction(self):
        self.close()

    def newConnectAction(self):
        self.newWindow = connectionWindow(self) #problematic self argument
        self.newWindow.show()
       

class connectionWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__(parent) 
        self.setWindowTitle("New Connection")

def main():
    app = QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I tried not including "self" as an argument when creating the second window. this seems to work but I don't know why. Isn't it important to define the parent of the new second window?

Comment: I suggest giving this a read... https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html

Comment: @Alexander thank you, that helped. I added Qt.WindowType.Window flag

Comment: @RoomTemperature You should use the parent argument with care. When used for windows, it's normally done to create modal windows (and in that case, you should use QDialog) or popup widgets that are closely related to the parent (like menus). In Qt, the parent/child relationship is mostly used to keep the object tree consistent and ensure that children get properly deleted whenever their parent is destroyed; if you don't need such automation and strict relation, and you don't need a modal window, don't use the parent argument. See [Object Trees & Ownership](//doc.qt.io/qt-6/objecttrees.html).

Comment: @musicamante thank you for that information! The reason I want a parent/child relationship for both windows is that I want the child window to access variables in the parent window, is that reasonable?

Comment: @RoomTemperature Then you were asking the wrong question. Communication between objects has nothing to do with Qt and its object tree (but respecting proper and consistent relationships between Qt objects obviously helps). You can access any objects from anywhere as long as you provide means to do it. In your case, you could even remove the `parent` from the `super().__init__()` and keep a reference to it as an instance attribute. If you need to pass arguments, then do it in the constructor (`def __init__(self, someargument):`) and pass them when you create the instance.

Comment: @RoomTemperature Keep in mind, though, that "child" (in general OOP terms, not just Qt) objects should not rely on or directly attempt to access their "parent" in order to work, instead it should be the parent's responsibility to act upon them in some ways, and that's where Qt signals come in play, which allow proper interaction between objects, no matter their reletionships. See this related post: [The most elegant way to communicate between parent and child using Signal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70692825).